# Django mailer import

Tags: django, django-templates, django-email

According to [the documentation on django-mailer](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer/blob/master/docs/usage.txt), to use django-mailer for all my emails, I just need to put this in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "mailer.backend.DbBackend"
```

Which I did.

But I get this error when I actually try to use `django-templated-email` to send my emails:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing email backend module mailer.backend: "No module named backend"
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**:

Looks like there is indeed no "backend" module inside the mailer package. Does this mean the documentation is incorrect? What should I do now; find another package to use?

[image: nothing]

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev Reinstalling did  not help, but I installed directly from the GitHub repository, and that finally fixed it. I'd accept your answer if you put it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is `backend.py` file in the mailer package, see [github repo](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer/tree/master/mailer). Try to reinstall `django-mailer` directly from github.